# aggregating based on max checkDate

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe:
all the fields are StringType

```
vehicleNumber ProductionNumber checkDate
123           345              24/03/2023 09:06
123           345              24/03/2023 09:06
123           345              24/03/2023 09:04
234           567              24/03/2023 09:05
234           567              24/03/2023 09:05
234           567              23/03/2023 09:05
```

I want to partition the df with `vehicleNumber` `ProductionNumber` `checkDate`

and I want to pick only the values with max `checkdate` based on `vehicleNumber` and `productionNumber` partition

output required is:

```
vehicleNumber ProductionNumber checkDate
123           345              24/03/2023 09:06
123           345              24/03/2023 09:06
234           567              24/03/2023 09:05
234           567              24/03/2023 09:05
```

tried below code it didnt work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Convert checkDate to datetime format
df = df.withColumn("checkDate", to_timestamp("checkDate", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))

# Define the window specification
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(["vehicleNumber", "ProductionNumber"]).orderBy("checkDate")

# Apply the window function and select the rows with max checkDate
maxDateDF = df.select("*", max("checkDate").over(windowSpec).alias("maxDate")) \
              .filter("checkDate = maxDate") \
              .drop("maxDate")

maxDateDF.display()
```

Comment: use window functions in apache spark, Window.partitionBy("vehicleNumber", "productionNumber") and then get the max over that window.

Comment: tried it but its not working as expected

Comment: can you please share what you did in your post ?

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import max, to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Convert checkDate to datetime format
df = df.withColumn("checkDate", to_timestamp("checkDate", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))

# Define the window specification
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(["vehicleNumber", "productionNumber"]).orderBy("checkDate")

# Apply the window function and select the rows with max checkDate
maxDateDF = df.select("*", max("checkDate").over(windowSpec).alias("maxDate")) \
              .filter("checkDate = maxDate") \
              .drop("maxDate")

maxDateDF.display()

Comment: can you add it to the post please ?

Comment: added now please check

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the orderBy close from your window `.orderBy("checkDate")`, so your window will be like this:

```
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(["vehicleNumber", "ProductionNumber"])
```

Why ? Because this is the default behaviour when an order by is specified, from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html)

> When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame (rowFrame,
> unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing) is used by default. When
> ordering is defined, a growing window frame (rangeFrame,
> unboundedPreceding, currentRow) is used by default.

Which means when there's no orderBy the window will be unbounded which means the whole partition, while when provided the window will be (rangeFrame, unboundedPreceding, currentRow) which means the previous rows till the current one in the specified order